# Is there a program that tracks the running times of certain processes?

Tags: windows-7, logging, time-management

I think I spend way too much time on computer games and would like to know exactly how much time I spend on them, in hopes that this will help me refrain myself from playing...

Is there a program that can give me a detailed report on how long certain processes run per day?

Comment: Like Steam client?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a program that can give me a detailed report on how long certain processes run per day?

[ProcrastiTracker](http://procrastitracker.com/) gives a detailed report, including per-process graphs of how long and exact times it was running.

[image: ProcrastiTracker]

Answer (score 2):

What about [XFire](http://www.xfire.com/) or [Raptr](http://raptr.com/) or [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/)? Every 3 of them can track TONS of games, AND custom games too. Check them out which fits your need. They are *made* for this. XFire just got a huge money 'investment' from Intel, so it'll become much better too.

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood my question: I need to track the amount of **time** I spend on these games, these don't seem to provide that functionality.

Comment: Well, you can't track Office with them... unless you add Office to Steam for example... but they do track times, and they are made for this purpose. Just my two cents.